# C# NAudio Auto Record

Tags: c#, naudio

and sorry for my English.

I am making a audio recorder. I am using NAudio framework for recording. I can record but not automaticly. I want to start recording when input volume is over the spesific level and stop recording and save as wav when bellow the spesific level. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to monitor the signal level by calling `StartRecording` and examining the sample values received. Don't be put off by the name `StartRecording` - all it means is that you are capturing samples from the soundcard. You don't need to write them to a file if you don't want to. The way to examine the sample values is using `BitConverter.ToInt16` on each pair of bytes in the input buffer (assuming you are recording 16 bit). It is then up to you to decide what constitutes enough volume to trigger recording. Once you have reached this level, you can start really "Recording" by writing the incoming buffers to a `WaveFileWriter`.